# How can we post ASCII art on Facebook wall?

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, ascii

In my app, I have a requirement to post the ASCII art from my iPhone app onto the Facebook wall post. But the problem I face is that Facebook font (Lucida Console) Changes the formatting of my ASCII art. I have made my ASCII art in Courier New.

Is there a way I can post my ASCII art on Facebook without having to re-format the whole thing?

Comment: Start by going to myspace.com. Seriously though, I don't think you can specify which font to use. You would have to make it look right using Lucida Console. Not to mention, it will probably change the way your original line breaks were used

Comment: I am not clearly getting what you said. Please explain more. I am a newbie.

Comment: ASCII art is dependent on which font you use. Unless you can specify the font to use (which I doubt you can), you will be unable to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Courier is a [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). That means, that every letter has the same space. That's why it is easy to use for ASCII art and popular for coding — as words with same length will always be at same positions.

From Facebook CSS:

```
font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
```

[Lucida Grande](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucida_Grande) is a [proportional font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion). i.e. an `i` uses much less space than an `m`. Words in different lines won't match very well.

### Edit

Have a look at [this Facebook group](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Symbols-and-ASCII-art-for-facebook/157400174899). The users compensate the absence of a monospaced font by

1. using just symbols with roughly the same width
2. filling room with short symbols like `.`

Monospaced:

```
 `♥♥'''''''''''''''♥♥`  
 `♥♥'''''''''''''''♥♥`
```

Proportional:

♥♥'''''''''''''''♥♥

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a Python script, only tested it with simple examples so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
'''
fbformat -- format ASCII for Facebook
'''
import sys, os
PRINTABLE = [' '] + map(chr, range(ord('!'), ord('~') + 1))
FB_ABLE = [u'\u3000'] + map(unichr, range(0xff01, 0xff5f))
TO_FB = dict(zip(PRINTABLE, FB_ABLE))
FROM_FB = dict(zip(FB_ABLE, PRINTABLE))
COMMAND = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))[0]
TEXT = sys.stdin.read().decode('utf8')
TO = ''.join([TO_FB.get(C, C) for C in TEXT])
FROM = ''.join([FROM_FB.get(C, C) for C in TEXT])
sys.stdout.write([TO, FROM][COMMAND == 'fbunformat'].encode('utf8'))
```

symlink it as `~/home/bin/fbformat` and `~/home/bin/fbunformat`, and make sure `~/home/bin` is in your `PATH`.

enter the following as test.txt:

```
YES!
\o/
 |
/ \
```

then:

```
jcomeau@aspire:~/rentacoder/gdavis$ fbformat < /tmp/test.txt
ＹＥＳ！
＼ｏ／
　｜
／　＼
jcomeau@aspire:~/rentacoder/gdavis$ fbformat < /tmp/test.txt | fbunformat
YES!
\o/
 |
/ \
```

resources: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms