# Displaying the ASCII Artwork in the UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ascii

I want to add the ascii artwork functionality into my existing Emoji App. I have seen some applications on the appstore, which displayed the ASCII Artwork. I donot have any idea from where i should start. Please help me in adding this functionality.

Comment: Pick a monospace font and make sure what ever you use to display the ascii art (UILabel,UIWebView,...) has enough width and height! Thats pretty much it.

Comment: if i have an ascii artwork, which i got from the internet, can i assign it to the UITextView without any modification, or how i should display it in a uitextview

Comment: this should be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342571/how-can-we-post-ascii-art-on-facebook-wall/4342646#4342646

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick a [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) so that the ascii art is displayed properly. You can check [iOSFonts.com](http://iosfonts.com/) for which fonts are supported on the devices you are targeting. To display the ascii art you could use a multiline `UILabel` ([set `numberOfLines` to 0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/numberOfLines)). A `UITextView` will work as well but remember that they are editable by default unless you set `editable` to `NO`.